# Turning underlines OFF in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, dvi, text-decorations

How do I get rid of *all* underlines under links in hyperref? I am processing to DVI, not PDF (because I am using some PS-specific graphing which is non-functional in pdflatex). I am specifying

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\hypersetup{linkcolor=MediumSlateBlue,urlcolor=Olive,
 colorlinks=true,linkbordercolor=Red,citebordercolor=Red, 
 filebordercolor=Red,runbordercolor=Red,menubordercolor=Red}
```

using Red to try to see what changes what, to work out what to type, but all my ToC and other links are still underlined in 100% blue (the text of links is correctly in MediumSlateBlue).

How do I turn **off** all underlining? All the pages I can find are about turning it **on**, and the manual doesn't appear to mention underlining (it talks about "borders" — is this an artifact of using regular latex rather then pdflatex?)

Answer (score 4):

It's a feature of `xdvi`; you can disable underlining by calling

```
xdvi -linkstyle 0 filename
```

From the man page:

```
-linkstyle
        (.LinkStyle)  Determines the style in which hyperlinks are displayed. Possi-
        ble values and their meanings are:

         0       No highlighting of links
         1       Underline links with link color
         2       No underlining, color text with link color
         3       Underline and display text colored with link color

        The values for link color are specified by the options/resources  -linkcolor
        and -visitedlinkcolor (which see).
```

Comment: Oww. That's something I didn't expect. Thanks for pointing this out. I gave up using xdvi years ago — I'm using kdvi and it doesn't seem to have a similar option. xdvi's interface is rather primitive compared with kdvi.  At least Okular seems to render the links as required (although its interface sucks as well, with all that space wasted on the LH side by a useless icon bar).