# removing underline from journal title when using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, natbib, apa-style, cleveref, ulem

When I am using `hyperref`, the package puts underline to the journal title in my references.
How can I get rid of this underline?

A similar question is asked here:
[Turning underlines OFF in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32721/turning-underlines-off-in-hyperref)

However, I am using pdflatex.

UPDATE: MWE upon request

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\let\bibhang\relax
\usepackage{natbib} % reference manager

\usepackage{ulem} %to strike the words

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

This a citation \citep{Goossens:1994}

\bibliography{biblo}

\end{document}
```

biblo.bib is:

```
@Book{Goossens:1994,
author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
title     = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
address   = {Reading Massachusetts},
year      = 1994}
```

Appearently, ulem is culprit, but I am still not sure how to remove underline, while I need ulem for other stuff.

Comment: MWE, please....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply load `ulem` with the option `normalem`, otherwise all `\emph`asized words will be underlined.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\let\bibhang\relax
\usepackage{natbib} % reference manager

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %to strike the words

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

This a citation \citep{Goossens:1994}

\bibliography{biblo}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead, if you want `\emph` to underline your text, don't use that option, but issue the command `\normalem` just before your bibliography, as in the folllowing example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\let\bibhang\relax
\usepackage{natbib} % reference manager

\usepackage{ulem} %to strike the words

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\emph{Underlined text}

This a citation \citep{Goossens:1994}

\normalem
\bibliography{biblo}

\end{document}
```